# PowerShell: Get 'tmp' environment variable raw value

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

```
$env:tmp

[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('tmp', 'User')

(get-item hkcu:\Environment).GetValue('tmp')
```

All above PowerShell snippets return `C:\Users\Roman\AppData\Local\Temp` value. I know that the value should be`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` (this I can see in regedit and in Environment Variables window).

I need to know 'original', but not 'resolved' value. How can I read this value in PowerShell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution that works for me:

```
(get-item hkcu:\Environment).GetValue('tmp', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
```

I discovered this GetValue overload after writing following PowerShell/C# code:

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Environment", $true);
$val = $reg.GetValue('tmp', $null, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions]::DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)
$val
$reg.Close()
```